# TSQL Multiple uses of Table defined by WITH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, with-statement

I think I may misunderstand why the with command is used. But can any one see what I am doing wrong. 
I want to do a query and use the results for two things. First I want to use the values to make some inserts into another table. Then I want to display the results to the user.

So I have something like this.

```
With temp as (
Select * from Table1 
)
INSERT INTO Table2 (table1_id) select id from temp
SELECT * from temp
```

And I get

> Error: Invalid object name 'temp'. SQLState:  S0002
>   ErrorCode: 208

Is this not what the with command is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined ***within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.***

Since the `insert` statement and the `select` statement are two different statements, the CTE is only valid for the `insert`.

As an alternative, you could consider using an [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 
)
INSERT INTO Table2 (table1_id) 
OUTPUT inserted.id
SELECT id FROM temp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative way to achieve what you wanna do. Try as follow.

```
Select * into #temp_table
from Table1 

INSERT INTO Table2 (table1_id) select id from #temp_table
SELECT * from #temp_table
```